# Handle successive fcm push notification

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications

i have set up my own push notification server to send notification to android devices.

I have handled the notification so on click it always open my custom activity whatever the app was in background or foreground.

**The working part** : When sending two **separated** notifications that means when the first notification is received i click on it so the activity is launched that's ok.
I re-send another notification so also when i click on it all goes well and the activity is relauched.Perfect!

**The NOT working part** : When sending two **successive** notifications the problem occurs.
When two notifications are received ..i open the first one the activity is launched but when i click on the second one nothing happens !!.

So i think it might be a solution in changing the Intent FLAG or Pending Intent.

I have searched for solutions but all were about handling the notification when app is in foreground or background which is not in my case.

This is my working code:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, News_description.class);
                    i.putExtra("title", title);
                    i.putExtra("message", message);
                    i.putExtra("image", image);
                    i.putExtra("time", time);
                    i.putExtra("date", date);
                    i.putExtra("click_action", click_action);
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
                    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT
                    );
                    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

                    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                            .setAutoCancel(true)
                            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                            .setVibrate(new long[]{status, status})
                            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                            .setContentText(title)
                            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(title))
                            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ahed_me)
                            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
                    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    int id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
                    manager.notify(id, builder.build());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

I can provide any further information.

Answer (score 0):

I have the Flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK and it works on my app.

```
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

Here my full code, it works perfect for me:

```
       Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

        PendingIntent contentIntent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0,
                        i, 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.alarm)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setContentTitle(title)
                        .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                        .setVibrate(vibrate)
                        .setLights(Color.BLUE, 3000, 1500)
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                                .bigText(body))
                        .setContentIntent(contentIntent)

                        .setContentText(body);


        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        int Unique_Integer_Numbe =  (int) ((new Date().getTime() / 1000L) % Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(Unique_Integer_Numbe, mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: Try what i did and it will not work with u.
Try sending two successive notifications then open one by one u will notice that the second notification will not work

Comment: I have found your problem it is: the PadingIntent use this: PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, i, 0);

Comment: I have use your code. first it not worked, then I change the PendingIntent it worked. But I have no more ideas

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED:**

```
public SomePushNotificationClass {

    private  static int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    String previousMessageID = "null";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Bundle data) {

        String messageID = data.getString("message_id");

        if (!messageID.equals(previousMessageID) && !messageID.isEmpty()) {
            previousMessageID = messageID;

            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            Intent it = new Intent(this, SomeActivity.class);
            it.putExtra("key_example_1", someValue);
            it.putExtra("key_example_2", someValue2);
            it.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | IntentCompat.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
               | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, it, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
            notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.some_drawable);
            notificationBuilder.setLargeIcon(someIcon);
            notificationBuilder.setContentTitle(someTitle);
            notificationBuilder.setStyle(new 

            // Optional
            NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(someText));
            notificationBuilder.setContentText(someText);
            notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);

            notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
            notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, 
            notificationBuilder.build());

            NOTIFICATION_ID++;
       }
   }
}
```

This is what you need:

```
 Intent it = new Intent(this, SomeActivity.class);
        it.putExtra("key_example_1", someValue);
        it.putExtra("key_example_2", someValue2);
        it.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | IntentCompat.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

Comment: Thanks i am trying it

Comment: the solution u provided i tested it and i got:

On press on first notification it shows the details of the second one because u provided : PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT

so still not working

Comment: i think the flags u added are working good but the problem still with pending intent because with your flags i can open the two notifications but still the data is being overrided because the use of FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT

Comment: Try single shot again with my code...On a side note ...make sure that your message have a different notification id to avoid the system recognizing it as a duplicate.

Comment: if you keep the original code that i gave, but add a check for message id...that should fix your problem...its working for me...I will update the answer

Comment: I am using this method : int id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
                    manager.notify(id, builder.build());

i will try yours.

Comment: Send the message_id from your own push notification server

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149757/discussion-between-mahdi-hraybi-and-andrew-el-masry).